# Is it idiomatic to say work in roles?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In a job interview, a candidate said

> I’ve worked in a variety of roles and companies, which I’ve learned a lot from, but now I’m
>   ready for a new challenge.

I am aware of the usage of "work in companies" but I cannot understand the usage of "work in roles". I guess a common way is

> I work as manager in AAZ corp (made up for discussion).

So, is it idiomatic to say work in roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really idiomatic to say "work in roles", because that doesn't communicate anything useful.  It is, however, entirely idiomatic to talk of working "in a variety of roles", "in various roles", "in multiple roles", "in challenging roles" and so on.